# strange happening with writing a script

Tags: javascript, button, hide, show

I click links in my page then my function in javascrpt will be done
I have this script:

```
<script>
  function useraccess()
{
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == "button"){
    inputs[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
                                   }
                                       }
}
</script>
```

and in the form:

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['isadmin'])
{
 echo '<script>useraccess();</script>';
}
?>
```

If I run it by clicking links that I wrote for a very short time it will show me the buttons and then they will be hide but! if I Include this line previous of `<script>` that I wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

with this line in codes:
No problem with my code and when I click links it will hide my buttons

I can't see the buttons that "after short time" they will hide

I mean they  "are" hide I can't see them even for a short time

I solved my problem very accidentally! 
cause I don't have file.js! I was just try something.

It is so interesting for me I have eager to know what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code will generate the following code in your HTML page:

> <script>useraccess();</script>

This will be run when the page loads, and will hide all your buttons. Exactly when it happens will depend where on the page you put that line. But running it has *no* connection with any buttons.

Since you talk about putting in the form, I'm guessing that you think that somehow making your PHP code generate that Javascript will affect your page. It won't. When your browser is displaying your page, the PHP has finished. You need to use some Javascript to observe the button clicks.

(If I've misunderstood your intention, I'm sorry).

**Edit** after reply from the OP:

Oh, I see. so you do want the buttons hidden right from the start, but they were appearing at first and then being hidden?

I think the problem then is that the 'useraccess' function is not run until after the page has loaded the form with its buttons.

A much better approach would be to change your PHP so as not to output the buttons at all, or output them disabled. Then they would not appear on the page at all, if the user was not privileged.

Comment: I don't want to see buttons cause it is a good issue for me to not see it  user that is not admin mustn't access buttons this user just have read only permission he/she can't be able to click any buton I wrote it with help of a friend and for a short time this user had access but by inserting that one line that I told now everything is Ok I just wanted to know the thing that I did! and I don't know.

Comment: I told that exactly previous of `<script> function useraceess..` I wrote that line and it is after my codes of PHP and it is previous of calling it That I told it is in Form